# Hibernate 4. Invalid Mapping Exception. Unable to read XML. Element type hibernate-mapping must be declared

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa

I have `InvalidMappingException` on `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure()` method call.

**Stack trace:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:109)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:488)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:484)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:657)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:740)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2188)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2160)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2140)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2093)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2008)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
    com.petrez.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    com.action.UserAction.setUser(UserAction.java:29)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: ; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 47; Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared.
    org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.reportError(XMLParser.java:1213)
    org.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.reportRecoverableXMLError(XMLValidator.java:1807)
    org.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.validateElementAndAttributes(XMLValidator.java:3633)
    org.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.callStartElement(XMLValidator.java:1229)
    org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.scanElement(XMLDocumentScanner.java:1806)
    org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner$ContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentScanner.java:949)
    org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.parseSome(XMLDocumentScanner.java:381)
    org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1098)
    org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:488)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:484)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:657)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:740)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2188)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2160)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2140)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2093)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2008)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
    com.petrez.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    com.action.UserAction.setUser(UserAction.java:29)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Config file:
**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LIBRARY</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">G190419g</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/petrez/model/Users.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Mapping file:
**Users.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.petrez.model">
    <class name="Users" table="Users" >
        <id name="id" column="Id" type="java.lang.Integer" >
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>

        <property name="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FirstName" length="45" />
        </property>

        <property name="lastName" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="LastName" length="45" />
        </property>

        <property name="eMail" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="Email" length="45" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So anybody can say me where is here a mistake? Thanks.

**UPD:** Project Structure.

[image: Project Structure]

Well. I didn't find a solution, but annotations helped me.

Comment: Somehow Hibernate has problems parsing your Users.hbm.xml file and doesn't know/understands the "hibernate-mapping". Because I'm using Annotation instead of config through hbm-files, I can't tell you more.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114046/hibernate-error-possibly-with-dtd-declaration

Comment: You Can Remove 'Package Name' in 'hibernate-mapping' attribute and run the project. Project runs successfullly. And I can tell you why you have that exception, to explain this all we need to know the package hierarchy and its classes. Otherwise it might be problem of DTD header in Hibernate mapping xml file

Comment: @Manish No. I have seen this question.

Comment: @Hareesh package name deleted. Project structure in update.

Answer (score 1):

Change your type of mappings from Java types to Hibernate types: For String i am giving as example:

```
 <property name="logMsg" type="string">
            <column name="LOG_MSG" length="35" />
        </property>
```